# How to stop/pause/remove the game timer in games using a Cube 2 Sauerbraten engine?

Tags: cube-2-sauerbraten

I enjoy playing [Banana Bread](https://kripken.github.io/misc-js-benchmarks/banana/index.html), and now am working on learning to edit and make my own maps. But with a 10 minute game timer, there's not a whole lot of time to make a ton of changes. Since Banana Bread uses a Cube 2 Sauerbraten engine, and can be controlled rather precisely if you know the correct command, I'm pretty sure there's a way to fix this. I just haven't found it yet, but maybe you have.

**How can I stop/pause/remove the game timer games using a Cube 2 Sauerbraten engine?**

What I mean by this is that after the timer would normally end, it instead keeps going and will allow me to edit the maps longer than normal. Ideal answer has a command I can type in or set of steps to accomplish this without downloading anything(I am on chromebook). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, first we are talking about the [Sauerbraten game](http://sauerbraten.org/), not Bananabread (which is a copy of Sauerbraten for the web). You can use the command `/coop` followed by the map name (which you can read by pressing tab or doing the command `/echo $mapname`).
`/coop turbine` for example.

If a map with that name already exists, it will be loaded in edit mode, otherwise an empty map will be created with that name. You can save maps with /savemap followed by the name, just be careful that if you "overwrite" one of the official maps you won't be able to play with it online.

Your saved maps can be accessed with /showcustommaps, if you want to play in a specific mode with them just type /instactf map name or /ffa map name, or /efficctf etc, you can see all available modes in the mode list .

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a solution, but typing `/coop` in the chat creates a blank map you can edit with no timer. You'll only get FFA and have to place the weapons yourself to get a good fight, but at least you have more than ten minutes.

Not quite the best answer since I'd like to keep the gamemode and map template the game started on. If you know that please answer.